# ccTouchesBegan not called

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, touches

I'm trying to implement `ccTouchesBegan` in my GameScene.

I've set `isTouchEnabled = YES`. I'm also calling `addStandardDelegate` on the `touchDispatcher`. Finally, in my `AppDelegate` i have `[glView setMultipleTouchEnabled:YES]`.

However, ccTouchesBegan is never called.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it!

I was registering touches on a previous layer, but the layer wasn't being dealloced because you have to "un-register" with the `onExit` method.

Long story short: `touchesBegan` was not being called on my GameLayer because it was being swallowed by another layer.

Answer (score 0):

Create one dummy application and try this:

```
@protocol CCStandardTouchDelegate <NSObject>
@optional
- (void)ccTouchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
- (void)ccTouchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
- (void)ccTouchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
- (void)ccTouchesCancelled:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
@end
```

May be it will help you..